# MSYS prints strange characters strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, msys

MSYS is printing some strange characters (whitespaces, nulls, etc.) to the terminal.  Makes the results of my unit tests a bit cryptic.  Any idea on how to fix this?  I'm looking into possibly piping it to a script that will clean the output.

```bsh
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m

Finished in 0.96875 seconds
←[32m2 examples, 0 failures←[0m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out that I can pipe the output through `cat`.  If anyone has a better idea, feel free to share!

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb | cat
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I think this solves the problem in an easier way than parsing commands throuh cat!

In Msys I set the TERM env variable to xterm and output is nicely printed.
You could consider adding

```
export TERM=xterm
```

to your .bashrc.